# HexDex Colour :Converting String to int removing 0

Tags: objective-c

I have a colour class set up where it takes red/blue/green values and uses them to create a hex string which is then used to return a colour. It can be initialized by providing a red, blue and green colour like this

```
 Colour *col = [[Colour alloc] initWithRed:200 Green:100 Blue:05];
```

The problem with this method is, if I pass in a value like 05, the 0 is stripped off, and just a 5 is passed in, so the blue will set to just be 5 rather than 05. My method to return a valid hex string is this

```
   -(NSString *)getHexString
    {
        NSString *hexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%x%x%x", iRed_i,iGreen_i,iBlue_i];
        hexString = [hexString uppercaseString];
        return hexString;
    }
```

It is expecting 2 values for each number to return the correct colour code, but the 0 is being stripped off meaning it returns an incorrect colour.

The other method I use to create a colour is to initialise the colour object with a hex string like this:

```
Colour *colour = [[Colour alloc] initWithHex:@"#782402"];
```

I then use scanner to separate the 3 values like so

```
if ([sHex_p hasPrefix:@"#"]) sHex_p = [sHex_p substringFromIndex:1];
            unsigned int outVal;
            NSString *sRed  = [sHex_p substringToIndex:2];
            NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:sRed];

            [scanner scanHexInt:&outVal];
            [self setRed:outVal];

            NSString *sGreen  = [[sHex_p substringFromIndex:2] substringToIndex:2];
            scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:sGreen];
            [scanner scanHexInt:&outVal];
            [self setGreen:outVal];

            NSString *sBlue = [sHex_p substringFromIndex:4];
            scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:sBlue];

            [scanner scanHexInt:&outVal];

            [self setBlue:outVal];
        }
```

But again same problem, in the hex string I provided the last 2 values are 02, but when converting from int to string, that 0 will be stripped out, so just a 2 will be passed, again ending up with an incorrect colour.

I really am unsure as what the best way to solve this is. Would be really grateful if someone could be point in the right direction.

I have been testing it using this site here

http://www.colorpicker.com/

Quick example I am trying to create this hex string "#DB4200". It requires red = 219 green = 66, blue = 00

But as the blue is just set to 0 when converts from string to int, ends up returning an incorrect colour, hex string ends up as "#DB420"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this actually involves three different  situations. First, 05 is just 5,
in both hexadecimal and  decimal bases. The problem is not  with your input in
this case, but  probably with the output. However, remember  this is a decimal
literal, so  if you want `#101010`  to mean 16 out  of 255 of each  color, use
hexadecimal constants like `0x10`.

Second: Regarding  output. The format string  you're using does not  enforce 2
digits in each color, and that's why your `05` becomes just `5`. You can force
the output of an integer (in hexadecimal form) to two digits padded with zeros
by using `%02x` instead of `%x`.

Third, is actually first. Looks like your method is working, but the output is
wrong.  Fixing  the  format  string  should  solve  this.  Anyway,  here's  an
alternative version using `sscanf`.

```
- (void)interpretHexString(NSString *str)
{
    int r,g,b;
    const char *s = [str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if (sscanf(s, "#%02x%02x%02x", &r, &g, &b) != 3) {
        /* problem with input */
    } else {
        /* set ivars */
        [self setRed:r];
        [self setGreen:g];
        [self setBlue:b];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, your solution worked perfectly! Was trying to figure that one out for good while there!!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad that is solved the problem. Note that my suggestion for scanning the value is indeed just a suggestion, but it would be nice to include a error checking part in yours, unless it already exists and is not shown in the example you posted ;-)

Comment: My error checking didn't bring this up before as my error checking just ensured the red/blue/green values were between 0 and 255 and while I had error checking on hex string being passed in was correct format, i.e beginning with hash, being 6 digits, I didn't do any error checking on the hex string produced, which is why I didn't notice this before. This is what I get for not making my testing extensive enough, will add an error check now to ensure I don't encounter problem like this before. Cheers!